Error when using sys.query_store_plan table in Azure Synapse Dedicated sq pool
I am getting below error when executing this query in my dedicated sql pool.
select * from sys.query_store_plan 

I do not use any columns in my selection. Not sure why this happens.
Error message:
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 102
Invalid column name 'has_compile_replay_script'.
Invalid column name 'is_optimized_plan_forcing_disabled'.
Invalid column name 'plan_type'.
Invalid column name 'plan_type_desc'.
All the above columns that shows in error message are not applicable for Azure Synapse and my query has no column selection.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Have you looked at 'B' for Azure Synapse?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#b-query-to-view-query-plan-results-in-azure-synapse-analytics

This is also mentioned in the documentation:

In Azure Synapse Analytics, using columns has_compile_replay_script, is_optimized_plan_forcing_disabled, plan_type, plan_type_desc results in an Invalid Column Name error as they aren't supported. See Example B for an example of how to use sys.query_store_plan in Azure Synapse Analytics.

As SELECT * will have all columns, this will include the columns which will give an error.
You should specify your SELECT statement without these columns like described in Example 'B' in the given URL:
SELECT TOP 100
    plan_id,
    query_id,
    plan_group_id,
    engine_version,
    compatibility_level,
    query_plan_hash,
    query_plan,
    is_online_index_plan,
    is_trivial_plan,
    is_parallel_plan,
    is_forced_plan,
    is_natively_compiled,
    force_failure_count,
    last_force_failure_reason,
    last_force_failure_reason_desc,
    count_compiles,
    initial_compile_start_time,
    last_compile_start_time,
    last_execution_time,
    avg_compile_duration,
    last_compile_duration,
    plan_forcing_type,
    plan_forcing_type_desc
FROM sys.query_store_plan
ORDER BY last_execution_time DESC;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#b-query-to-view-query-plan-results-in-azure-synapse-analytics
